# How to add picture to Dynamically created Picturebox, on a drag drop event

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a Function as Mentioned below. I need to add N number of picturebox if user drop a small Image on panel.
With the code below (On Drag and Drop event of form) I am able to add a dynamic picturebox. But I am facing two problems.

1. It adds only 1 picturebox. If I drag and drop something, It only replace Picture in Picturebox.
2. I need to Add new picturebox in row and column wise, depending on the width of the Panel

---

```
Public Function addPic(ByVal pic As Image, ByVal pName As String)
    Dim PB As New PictureBox
    With PB
        .Name = pName
        .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(5, 5)
        .Size = New Size(50, 50)
        .BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center
        .Image = pic
        '  Note you can set more of the PicBox's Properties here
    End With

    thePanel.Controls.Add(PB)
    RichTextBox1.Controls.Add(PB)
    '  This is the line that sometimes catches people out!

    'Me.Controls.Add(PB)
    PB.BringToFront()

    '  Wire this control up to an appropriate event handler
    ' AddHandler PB.Click, AddressOf MyPicClicked

    AddHandler PB.MouseDown, AddressOf PictureBox_MouseHover
    AddHandler PB.MouseLeave, AddressOf PictureBox_MouseLeave
    ' AddHandler PB.Paint, AddressOf PictureBox_Paint
    Return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate how many images can fit in the panel:

```
numImagesWide = thePanel.ActualWidth / image.Width
numImagesHigh = thePanel.ActualHeight/ image.Height
```

you can safely do this with integer arithmetic as you just need the whole number of images that will fit.

Then you can loop over `numImagesWide` and `numImagesHigh` adding a new `PictureBox` each time round the loop. All the code in your current method wants to go inside the loop - so it might be cleaner to write a wrapper method that loops and calls your current method.